# how to make bot to search particular intent when a user selects particular selection using luis c# iam trying using switch case please guide me

Tags: chatbot, azure-language-understanding

iam trying to call particular intent when someone selects any intent eg:if user selects cmtools intent then the user can ask questions related to cmtools only. Other than cmtools if user asks question then the bot should rply Sorry not a good match.Please help me with the code to call intents from switch case or any other idea is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace Microsoft.Bot.Sample.LuisBot

{
    [LuisModel("id","key")]

    [Serializable]

     public class BasicLuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
     {

    // QnA Maker global settings
    // assumes all KBs are created with same Azure service
    static string qnamaker_endpointKey = "endpointkey";
    static string qnamaker_endpointDomain = "chatbot";

    // QnA Maker Knowledge base
    static string AIS_KB= "id1";
    static string Speed_KB = "id2";
    static string CMTools_KB = "id3";
    // QnA Maker Finance Knowledge base


    // Instantiate the knowledge bases
    public QnAMakerService AIS_KBQnAService = new QnAMakerService("https://" + qnamaker_endpointDomain + ".azurewebsites.net", AIS_KB, qnamaker_endpointKey);
    public QnAMakerService Speed_KBQnAService = new QnAMakerService("https://" + qnamaker_endpointDomain + ".azurewebsites.net", Speed_KB, qnamaker_endpointKey);
    public QnAMakerService CMTools_KBQnAService = new QnAMakerService("https://" + qnamaker_endpointDomain + ".azurewebsites.net", CMTools_KB, qnamaker_endpointKey);
public const string AIS_KBIntent = "AIS_KB";
public const string Speed_KBIntent = "Speed_KB"; // new intent
public const string CMTools_KBIntent = "CMTools_KB"; // new intent

        public class Metadata

{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public IList<string> questions { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public double score { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public IList<object> keywords { get; set; }
    public IList<Metadata> metadata { get; set; }
}

public class QnAAnswer
{
    public IList<Answer> answers { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class QnAMakerService
{
    private string qnaServiceHostName;
    private string knowledgeBaseId;
    private string endpointKey;

    public QnAMakerService(string hostName, string kbId, string endpointkey)
    {
        qnaServiceHostName = hostName;
        knowledgeBaseId = kbId;
        endpointKey = endpointkey;

    }
    async Task<string> Post(string uri, string body)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
            request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "EndpointKey " + endpointKey);

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            return  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
    public async Task<string> GetAnswer(string question)
    {
        string uri = qnaServiceHostName + "/qnamaker/knowledgebases/" + knowledgeBaseId + "/generateAnswer";
        string questionJSON = @"{'question': '" + question + "'}";

        var response = await Post(uri, questionJSON);

        var answers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QnAAnswer>(response);
        if (answers.answers.Count > 0)
        {
            return answers.answers[0].answer;
        }
        else
        {
            return "No good match found.";
        }
    }
}
 public enum Selection
                 {
                 CMTools, AIS, Speed
                 } 


      [LuisIntent("AppSelection")]
private async Task AppSelection(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
     var options = new Selection[] { Selection.CMTools, Selection.AIS, Selection.Speed };
    var descriptions = new string[] { "CMTools", "AIS", "Speed" };
   PromptDialog.Choice<Selection>(context, ResumeAfterOrderSelectionClarification,options, "Please choose your application?", descriptions: descriptions );
}

private async Task ResumeAfterOrderSelectionClarification(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Selection> result,LuisResult result1)
{
     var selection = await result;
    await context.PostAsync($"Thanks for choosing  {selection}. how can I help you ?");


switch(selection){
    case CMTools:
    await context.PostAsync($"CMTools");
       //code needed to call CMTools_KB intent
        break;

    case AIS:

        await context.PostAsync($"AIS_KB");
        //code needed to call AIS_KB intent
        break;

    case Speed:
          await context.PostAsync($"Speed_KB");
        // Ask the HR knowledge base
       //code needed to call Speed_KB intent
        break;
     default:
     await context.PostAsync($"testing.........");

}   
}


         [LuisIntent("")]
         [LuisIntent("None")]
          public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
    }

     [LuisIntent("AIS_KB")]
    public async Task AIS_KBIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        // Ask the HR knowledge base
        var qnaMakerAnswer = await AIS_KBQnAService.GetAnswer(result.Query);
        await context.PostAsync($"{qnaMakerAnswer}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("Speed_KB")]
    public async Task Speed_KBIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        // Ask the HR knowledge base
        var qnaMakerAnswer = await Speed_KBQnAService.GetAnswer(result.Query);
        await context.PostAsync($"{qnaMakerAnswer}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }


    [LuisIntent("CMTools_KB")]
    public async Task CMTools_KBIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        // Ask the HR knowledge base
        var qnaMakerAnswer = await CMTools_KBQnAService.GetAnswer(result.Query);
        await context.PostAsync($"{qnaMakerAnswer}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

     private async Task ShowLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
     {
        await context.PostAsync($"Sorry , I am not able to help you with this questions,Please connect our L2 Support Group");
        var qnaMakerAnswer = await CMTools_KBQnAService.GetAnswer(result.Query);
        await context.PostAsync($"{qnaMakerAnswer}");
         await context.PostAsync($"it is finished ");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
     }

     }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to reduce the amount of your code to make more clear which part is relevant to your question?

Comment: Just to clarify, by 'if user selects cmtools intent then the user can ask questions related to cmtools only' do you mean, the user can choose from a list? Because LUIS doesn't quite work this way.